# How to Tell Compiler the Variable Will Exist

Tags: c#, visual-studio

How do you tell Visual Studio to trust that a variable will exist at the time it is needed. Here's my code:

```
            string line;
        bool fileExists = false;
        System.IO.StreamReader fileIn;
        System.IO.StreamWriter fileOut;

        fileIn = new System.IO.StreamReader(inputFile);

        while ((line = fileIn.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            if (line.Length > 0 && line.Substring(0, 1) == "O")
            {
                _parent.StatusOutput(line);
                if (fileExists)
                {
                    // close the existing file ...
                    fileOut.WriteLine();
                    fileOut.WriteLine();
                    fileOut.WriteLine("%");
                    fileOut.Close();
                }
                // create a new file ...
                fileOut = new System.IO.StreamWriter(outputFolder + @"\" + line);
                fileExists = true;
                fileOut.WriteLine();
                fileOut.WriteLine("%");
                fileOut.WriteLine(line);
            }
            else if (line.Length == 0)
            {
                _parent.StatusOutput("Blank line.");
                if (fileExists) fileOut.WriteLine();
            }
            else if (line.Length > 0 && line == "%")
            {
                _parent.StatusOutput("BO/EOF found.");
                // do nothing ...
            }
            else
            {
                // everything else goes to the new file ...
                if (fileExists) fileOut.WriteLine();
            }
        }    // while ...
        
        // close the last file ...
        fileOut.WriteLine();
        fileOut.WriteLine();
        fileOut.WriteLine("%");
        fileOut.Close();
        fileIn.Close();
```

The error is when I try to write to fileOut. I know that the fileOut write will exist in time, but the compiler doesn't.

How can I get the compiler to ignore that?

Comment: What does *exist at the time it is needed* means? it needs to be declared explicitly before using it.

Comment: To avoid *use of unassigned local*: `System.IO.StreamReader fileIn = null;` (or narrow its scope)

Comment: @BernieHunt: What error?

Comment: In at least one case, it *won't* be set - if `fileIn.ReadLine()` returns `null` during its first call. I'd suggest guarding access after the `while` as you have elsewhere and also consider using `fileOut`s `null`/`not null` nature as the flag rather than using a separate `bool`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could assign `null` to `fileOut` when it is declared and then check if it is not null:

```
    string line;
    System.IO.StreamReader fileIn;
    System.IO.StreamWriter fileOut = null;

    fileIn = new System.IO.StreamReader(inputFile);

    while ((line = fileIn.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if (line.Length > 0 && line.Substring(0, 1) == "O")
        {
            _parent.StatusOutput(line);
            if (fileOut != null)
            {
                // close the existing file ...
                fileOut.WriteLine();
                fileOut.WriteLine();
                fileOut.WriteLine("%");
                fileOut.Close();
            }

            // create a new file ...
            fileOut = new System.IO.StreamWriter(outputFolder + @"\" + line);
            fileOut.WriteLine();
            fileOut.WriteLine("%");
            fileOut.WriteLine(line);
```

Comment: @TejasVaishnav That is the code of OP. I modified only the part of code, that has to do with the question. This community is not about coding patterns!

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how would you refactor this code? Would you use `fileOut.Writeline("\n\n%");` or `fileOut.WriteLine(Environment.Newline+Environment.Newline+"%");`?

Comment: @ Romano Zumbé  you are correct, misunderstood the code in hurry. I was focusing on System.IO.StreamWriter fileOut = null; not NewLine etc. Rolling back my comments, apologies!

Answer (score 0):

you have to initialize before use it like move fileOut initialization just after fileIn.

```
fileIn = new System.IO.StreamReader(inputFile);

fileOut = new System.IO.StreamWriter(outputFolder + @"\" + line);
```

Comment: I think it is because your code is wrong. `fileOut` is created with a path, that doesn't exist because `line` is not initialized at that point. Additionally it is pointless to do it. Assigning a value of null is totally sufficient there.